# Remove items from select list which have been appended in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My form allows users to select a vehicle type, which then, using Jquery, appends those values which are checked, to my select list.

All good, except I need to handle the de-selection of vehicles, which should remove the value in the select list.

You should be able to see that on append, I attribute a class of "select_option" which is what I use to try and remove this from the select.  However, it isn't working.

How can I remove those that are de-selected?

HTML

```
<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicles" data-name="Bike" value="Bike">Bike
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicles" data-name="Car" value="Car">Car
</form>

<select name="choose_car" id="choose_car">
     <option value=""class="select_option">Choose car</option>
</select>
```

JQUERY

```
$('.vehicles').click(function(){

    $('#choose_car').append('<option value=' + $(this).val() + ' class=\'select_option\'>' + $(this).data("name")) + '</option>';

    $.each($(".vehicles:not(:checked"), function(){
        $('option.select_option').remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the values of the non-checked vehicles so you only remove those options:

```
$(".vehicles:not(:checked)").each(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('#choose_car option.select_option[value=' + val + ']').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete working example (add and remove in the same function) :

each time you check or uncheck, it adds or remove the item from the list

you can drop the `select_option` class

http://jsfiddle.net/dgp4bv3j/1/

```js
$(function() {
    $("[type='checkbox']").on("change", function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#choose_vehicle").append("<option value=\"" + $(this).val() + "\">" + $(this).val() + "</option>");
        } else {
            $("#choose_vehicle option[value='" + $(this).val() + "']").remove();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicles" data-name="Bike" value="Bike">Bike
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicles" data-name="Car" value="Car">Car
</form>

<select name="choose_vehicle" id="choose_vehicle">
     <option value="">Choose vehicle</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?
http://jsfiddle.net/0hk8rLcj/

```
$('[name=vehicles]').click(function(){


    $('#choose_car').append('<option value=' + $(this).val() + ' class=\'select_option\'>' + $(this).data("name")) + '</option>';

    $("[name=vehicles]:not(:checked)").each(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('#choose_car option.select_option[value=' + val + ']').remove();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I completed a similar answer to the others: http://jsfiddle.net/h7w8x7sh/15/

```
$('.vehicles').click(function(){
var chooseCar = $('#choose_car');

if ($(this).prop('checked')) { 
    chooseCar.append('<option value=' + $(this).val() + ' class=\'select_option\'>' + $(this).data("name") + '</option>');
}
else {
    var ogValue = $(this).val();
    $('#choose_car option').each(function()  {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (ogValue == value) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
}
});
```

does the same thing pretty much but I am including it because I spent some time writing it up. But yeah you should change the $('.vehicles') unless they are classes (I changed them to classes in my fiddle).